# Inflating error with BottomNavigationView and Splash Screen API Android XML

Tags: android, splash-screen, bottomnavigationview

I've faced with problem of inflating activity layout after adding to it BottomNavigationView

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@android:color/transparent"
            app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
            app:itemRippleColor="@null"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/indicatorView"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|start"
                android:background="@color/red"/>
        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

The problem is that it requires (as it shows in exception log) AppCompat theme, but i need to set splash theme for activity. How i can solve such problem?

```
<activity
            android:name=".presentation.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.PexelsViews.Splash"> // works after removing this
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```